How to override Google My Business API error "STALE_DATA"
Google has a bad habit of overwriting location's info with 'suggested edits', based on 'users suggestions or other available data'.
We have function to correcting discrepancies of google's data with local db, but it is not always working when it tries to propagate locations affected by 'suggested edits', instead we receive  this:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "STALE_DATA",
"domain": "mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"field_mask": "regular_hours"
}
}
]
}
}

and if we check error codes, it seems like the only way to overwrite those 'suggested values' to the one's I need is to go to business.google.com and change values manually.
enter image description here
Are there any way to override this block with api call, without using google business UI? Maybe some specific field mask?
Or if there at least some timeout on this block? As far as I can tell, it is lifted after several days, but maybe someone knows specific number, because documentation is very scrace on the topic
